# Lock Integer cast to enum type or show warning at least

Tags: objective-c, enums, compiler-warnings

Is there a way to show warning when I provide Integer number as an argument that requires some enum type?

```
// Enum definition
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, TVScheduleSortBy) {
        TVScheduleSortByDisplayOrder,
        TVScheduleSortBySlotStartDate,
        TVScheduleSortBySlotEndDate
    };

// Method declaration
- (void)sortBy:(TVScheduleSortBy)sortBy order:(SortDataOrder)order;

// Good case .. no warnings
[object sortBy:(TVScheduleSortByDisplayOrder) order:(SortDataOrderDefault)];

// Bad case .. I should get at least compiler warning
[object sortBy:(10) order:(SortDataOrderDefault)];
```

Comment: What about using `typedef enum` rather than `NS_ENUM(NSUInteger,...)`?

Comment: This approach combines the best of all of the aforementioned approaches, and even provides hints to the compiler for type-checking and switch statement completeness. http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/

Comment: Nevermind; I've just tried it on Linux using gcc and it doesn't provide a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the warning for "implicit enum conversions". It's off by default.

How to find this: Click on the project, then on the target, "build settings", type "enum" in the search field, find three enum related warnings.

Comment: It's ok but this warning works only when I pass different enumeration as an argument so it will show warning when I try to call [getSelectionsReqData sortBy:(EventSortByDisplayOrder) order:(SortDataOrderDefault)]; I expect TVScheduleSortBy but I provide EventSortBy but it shows no warning when I want to use Integer like this: [object sortBy:(10) order:(SortDataOrderDefault)];